# BQ Aquaris E4.5 won't boot - Screen flashes and phone stops

Tags: boot, ubuntu-touch, phone, bq

I've been using this phone for a while now, but suddenly it won't boot anymore.

I press the power button and after 3 seconds the screens lights up for a split second and shuts back down.

If I keep pressing the power button this just repeats.

I can enter the boot menu by pressing the power button + the volume up button, but none of the entries actually do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my question is a little bit stupid but is the phone charged ?
Because I noticed on my phone that battery can go from 50% to 1% really fast.
Try to do it when your phone is connected to supply power.

If it's not come from battery try to remove SD card and SIM.